# Bootstrap: Input boxes go offscreen when making individual rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I wanted to have each input box to be a certain size, I was told I had to make a new row for each one in order to do that. I'm pretty new to bootstrap and coding in general so I'm not sure how to fix this.

I'm using Bootstrap 4, if the version matters..

It worked but for some reason it goes off screen to the left and you can only see half of the input box.

Help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <h1>Team Selector</h1>
</head>
<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
    <label for="inputsm">Player 1</label>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputsm" type="text" 
placeholder="Name here">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
   <div class="col-xs-3">
    <label for="inputsm">Player 2</label>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputsm" type="text" 
placeholder="Name here">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <label for="inputsm">Player 3</label>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputsm" type="text" 
placeholder="Name here">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form group row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputsm">Player 4</label>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputsm" type="text" 
placeholder="Name here">
    </div>
  </div>

</form>



</html>
```

Comment: can you screen shot the output?

Comment: Hi,
Can you please check if you get script error in the console?

Comment: You can just change the col-xs-3 to col-sm-3 and it will be fixed.

Comment: Hi @Buckets just remove the `row` the row in every `<div class="form group row">` and it will be fixed. or you can just follow [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-horizontal) pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Bootstrap4, If you add `.row` to `.form-group` it will apply property of `row` class which is

```
.row {
margin-right: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;
}
```

So in your case `margin-left: -15px` is applying so some part is missing. so to make individual rows try adding `col-12` or simply remove `row`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <div class="form-group col-12">
    <div class="col-3">
    <label for="inputsm">Player 1</label>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputsm" type="text" 
placeholder="Name here">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-12">
   <div class="col-3">
    <label for="inputsm">Player 2</label>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputsm" type="text" 
placeholder="Name here">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-12">
  <div class="col-3">
    <label for="inputsm">Player 3</label>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputsm" type="text" 
placeholder="Name here">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form group col-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputsm">Player 4</label>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputsm" type="text" 
placeholder="Name here">
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: This works but when I do this, the input box size takes up the entire space, I was trying to make them smaller, is there any other workaround using this?

Comment: i think `xs` is deprecated in Bootstrap 4 replace it with `col-sm-3` or simply `col-3` updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some changes in your code like this.
copy and paste this code and see. Maybe this helps you.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
    <label for="inputsm">Player 1</label>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputsm" type="text" 
placeholder="Name here">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
   <div class="col-xs-3">
    <label for="inputsm">Player 2</label>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputsm" type="text" 
placeholder="Name here">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <label for="inputsm">Player 3</label>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputsm" type="text" 
placeholder="Name here">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form group row">
     <div class="col-xs-3">
    <label for="inputsm">Player 4</label>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="inputsm" type="text" 
placeholder="Name here">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: OP asking for Bootstrap 4 not Bootstrap 3

Comment: This work on all bootstrap version. Remove this <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> add you desire version

Comment: check this fiddle your code with bootstrap 4 https://jsfiddle.net/jqu311ta/

Comment: So you have to remove Class "row " from every div in your code for solution